# How can I take long exposure photos with a webcam?

Tags: exposure, long-exposure, webcam

I have a very simple webcam made by A4tech. It already has an exposure function (in its settings) and it's good in low light.

I want to be able to take even longer exposures. I have found this but I'm unable to select my webcam with it, so I have no idea how well it will work, if at all.

Is there any software that will allow me to take long exposure images from my simple webcam?

Comment: Few questions, do you already have a specific model webcam in mind? Do you want to adjust the exposure or actually adjust the shutter speed?

Comment: I have a very simple webcam. It is by A4tech. It already has exposure function (in its settings) and good at low light. I just want to do it more. I have found http://www.nimisis.com/projects/exposure.php but unable to select my webcam with it, so I have no idea how good it will work

Answer (score 2):

Modifying you webcam for long exposures might be possible, but it really depends on what model you are using.

The modification requires you to disassemble the webcam unit and modify the electronics inside it. You can try to look with f. ex. google "your_camera_make/model long exposure mod". 
Many astrophotography sites also have a lot of information abt. this kind of modification.

The nimesis software actually stacks a lot of short exposures to one picture which would appear to have long exposure, but it is not the same as a real long exposure.